# python html2pdf not generating pdf for bulk data

Tags: python, reportlab, html2pdf, pisa

I am using html2pdf to generate pdf reports, which does not generate pdf if there is large volume of data/records. I have 5000 records & it will covers 400+ pdfs pages. If the data/records are only 1000(covers up-to 80-85 pdf pages), it generated successfully. But for above that its failing completely. Is there any solution or should I need to use any other plugins.

I uses **write_pdf** function

**html2pdf.py**

```
from django import http 
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
from django.template.loader import get_template 
from django.template import Context 
import ho.pisa as pisa 
import cStringIO as StringIO 
import cgi, os 
from django.conf import settings 
from datetime import datetime  

def fetch_resources(uri, rel):  
   path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace("//", ""))  
   return path  

def write_pdf(template_src, context_dict, filename):
    os.chdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/pathtofoldertosave/')
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html  = template.render(context)
    result = open(filename, 'wb') 

    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(
        html.encode("UTF-8")), result,link_callback=fetch_resources)
    result.close()
    return str(settings.MEDIA_URL)+'/pathtofoldertosave/'+str(filename)  


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict,file_name):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html  = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result, link_callback=fetch_resources)
    if not pdf.err:         
         response = HttpResponse( result.getvalue() )           response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'        
         response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+file_name;       
         return response
    return http.HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % cgi.escape(html))
```

Function for generating report is: **report.py**

```
def reportFun(request):     
    mem  = Member.objects.all()
    FileName = "Report_"+datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M')+".pdf"
    fname = "http://"+str(request.META['HTTP_HOST'])+"/"+write_pdf('report_pdf.html',{'pagesize':'A4','data':mem}, FileName) 
    return render_to_response("report.html",{'result':mem,'fname':fname}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Show what you have done? Some relevant piece of code will definitely help

Comment: Your can split the data/records to smaller package and then cover to pdf.

Comment: @saul is that a good solution? I think it will take more time for pdf generation.

Comment: @Nabin I have added the code..